# Converting GETDATE() to Hijri date to yyyymmdd

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, hijri, formatdatetime

I am trying to get the Hijri GETDATE() and convert it into this format yyyymmdd

I have already tried this script

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 131)
```

but it gives me this format ( 16/06/1438 ) and what I actually need is (1438/06/16)

Comment: This is very well documented in the [SO Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/1471/dates#t=201703141241406432461)

Comment: There's no built in conversion to get what you're asking for - you'd need to assemble it yourself using lots of string mangling - or, if possible, do this formatting in another layer that hopefully has better calendar/localization/formatting tools available than those found in T-SQL.

Comment: Depending on your SQL Server version (tag it please), you might be able to use Format

Comment: It's already solved and I'm using SQL2012 @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: The usual thing to do now is post your solution so that everyone can benefit, or at least give the answers below some closure.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server does not offer a wealth of formatting options for such dates, so just construct it yourself:

```
SELECT (RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 131), 4) + '/' +
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 131)
       ) as hj_yyyymmdd
```

Oops.  Right idea, wrong implementation:

```
SELECT (RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 131), 4) +
        SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 131), 3, 4) +
        LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 131), 2)
   ) AS hj_yyyymmdd
```

Comment: Do you not have to reverse the day/month elements also? OP has requested 1438/06/16, your code produces 1438/16/06

Comment: Thank you very much, your script just did the magic @GordonLinoff

Comment: @Matt - as with many of the other answers here, you're missing the key point - the conversion needs to give the date in the Hijri calendar, *not* the Gregorian one.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I see now! answer removed

Comment: Here you go @Nick.McDermaid

Answer (score 2):

If you are having SQL Server 2012 and above,

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE()+1,'yyyy/MM/dd','ar')
```

It will give you the below result for the date `2017/03/14`

```
1438/06/16
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below query :

```
SELECT FORMAT ( GETDATE(), 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'ar-SA' )
```

Comment: The ‍‍‍```FORMAT``` function was introduced with ```SQL Server 2012``` and as pointed in the docs it is available in all supported versions.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to `convert` to `varchar` then `date` then `varchar` again.

Using `format() with 'ar-SA'` seems to return 1 day earlier than using `convert()` with style `131`.

```
select Method='multiconvert'
  ,conversion = convert(varchar(10)
    ,convert(date,convert(varchar(12),getdate(),131),103),112)
union all 
select 'format'
  , format ( getdate(), 'yyyyMMdd', 'ar-SA' )
union all
select 'style131'
  ,convert(varchar(12),getdate(),131)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/LIX82417

returns

```
+--------------+--------------+
|    Method    |  conversion  |
+--------------+--------------+
| multiconvert | 14380616     |
| format       | 14380615     |
| style131     | 16/06/1438   |
+--------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with 120:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the following query:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120),'-','/')
```